# Dotnetnuke with responsive skin

Tags: dotnetnuke, mobile-website, dotnetnuke-module

Is there a way to mark containers by numbers so that they show one after another in a certain order when responsive skin is used (when mobile device loads the page)?

I am using "Tidy" responsive skin and my plan is to have a module that sits on every page and gets "Request.Browser.Browser" on load so if it's a mobile browser I just plan to add this "?SkinSrc=%5BG%5DSkins/Tidy/TidySocial&ContainerSrc=%5BG%5DContainers/Tidy/PanelGrey" to my url and reload the page with Tidy skin, while making a Session variable that the user is on mobile. The problem is that containers with modules (html module, gallery, my custom modules) are not ordered one after another in a way I would like them to be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't really possible within DNN. The way to handle responsiveness and order is to control the order of the panes and modules within those panes when they are placed on the page (or change the order after). You can't easily target modules once they are on the page to control their positioning without doing custom development within the skin that would need to know details about the modules and locations of those.

Comment: hi Chris, thanks for your templates! As for the skins, I will make a copy of the page that I want to see with a mobile skin on a mobile device, apply the mobile skin on that new page, rearrange the modules as I want them to show on a mobile device, hide it from the menu and link it with the desktop version of the page in Admin - Site Redirection Management.

Answer (score 1):

ivan

you need to Change mobie.css of tidy to get you desire result

it is not possible in DNN by default

Latest DNN Install has responsive feature which is also good.